# What privileges are required for APEX schema users?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In Oracle Application Express you can create a workspace choosing creating a new database schema to associate with the workspace. Also there's an option to **"reuse"** a schema.

If you reuse a schema, which was created in a process of creation of another workspace, it's clear that everything will be ok.

But what if I want to use one of existing schemas which I once created. How this database schema should be prepared for use by an APEX workspace? What privileges should be given and to whom?

And the second question - If I have all my PL/SQL code in the existing schema `code`, what privileges should be given and to whom in order to be able to use packages from this schema by APEX applications in my workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of practical recommendations, but it should just be whatever tables your application should have access to.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/priv_db_user.htm#HTMDB28636

On a similar note, this should generally be limited to SELECT & EXECUTE privileges. Any DML should be done within PL/SQL package APIs.

So this all means the standard security you may be familiar with applies. Define a parsing schema for your application that has minimal access, and your packages may live in another schema, doing the grunt work for your parsing schema.

Comment: So, If I, for instance, created a schema `apex_app` for my workspace, and I have a package `emp` in my schema `code`, the only privilege I need to grant is `grant execute on code.emp to apex_app`? Do I need to assign schema `code` to the workspace in the instance administration panel in order to be able to execute PL/SQL code from it?

Comment: No, once you've granted execute on the package to the parsing schema of the application, the app may now refer to it with `code.emp` notation.

Comment: It seems these grants are also needed in order to creating a workspace be possible: `alter user apex_app quota unlimited on <apex_app_tablespace>; grant unlimited tablespace to apex_app;`

Comment: What's the point to assign a schema to a workspace in instance administration panel then? Is there any particular purpose?

Comment: you could have multiple workspaces, but only certain workspaces may access particular schemas. Or if you have only 1 workspace, you can control what schemas it has access to.